# Gradle building rest spring app can't find main class

Tags: java, spring, rest, gradle

I'm trying to do a http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ tutorial, and I did everything like it is in tutorial.

When I was trying to build with gradle with the gradle.build from the tutorial gradle build failed because of missing

```
springBoot {
  mainClass = "main.java.hello.Application"
}
```

I did add it and now compilation start and finish correctly, but as soon as I'm trying to do

> java -jar build/libs/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar

It throws an error [image]

I have no idea what to do with it. Any help?

Comment: It happened to me after changing module name. Executing `gradle clean` before running the application fixed it for me

Comment: This has happened to me a couple of times in a particular porject. To solve it, all I had to do was rebuild the project and it then found the main class along with other packages etc. (From IntelliJ on the top level navigation bar -> Build -> Rebuild project)

Answer (score 10):

It should be `hello.Application`. `main/java` is a part of package name / project dir structure.

When added the following piece of code to *build.gradle*:

```
springBoot {
  mainClass = "hello.Application"
}
```

both `./gradlew clean bootRun` and `./gradlew clean build` with `java -jar build/libs/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar` work well.

Comment: Well, I was using gradle build, when i use ./gradlew its not recognized as internal or external command. Dunno why?

Comment: It's windows or linux? If linux try to set `chmod +x gradlew`. Is `gradlew` file present?

Comment: To move from `gradle build` to `./gradlew build` you first have to issue `gradle wrapper`

Answer (score 3):

The above error is due to the build do not includes our Web RESTful Service main application class files into the `gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar` file because of the src/main/java/hello, folder is not under the gradle build scope.

In order to avoid the above error or any other errors for `https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/` tutorial

Please follow the steps below.

My Folder structure as follows.

> C:\MyWebService\src\main\java\hello

Put your build.gradle file under your main folder e.g `"MyWebService"` not in your hello or any other folder hence "gradle build' will be successful.

Using DOS cmd navigate to your main folder `e.g C:\MyWebService\` where src should be the first sub folder.

Run the gradle commands.

> gradle
>
> gradle tasks
>
> gradle wrapper
>
> gradlew clean build         -- final build
>
> or gradlew clean bootRun    -- run before build

You will find your `gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar` under your `C:\MyWebService\build\libs folder.`

Finally invoke spring web service from main folder `e.g C:\MyWebService\`

> java -jar build/libs/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar

To check Spring RESTful Web Service by hitting below url in the browser, JSON data will be returned.

> http://localhost:8080/greeting

```
{"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

Now you should be successful with completing the `Spring RESTful Web Service` tutorial.

> N.B: Please do not modify your original `build.gradle` file provided
>   on the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'application'
```

Add the above highlighted line in the build.gradle